# Different prettier's check results

Tags: github-actions, prettier

I have script `"lint:prettier": "prettier --check --ignore-unknown \"**/*.*\"",`. Then I run it, I get successful result but in github actions I getting erorrs

Github action lint-action workflow:

```
- name: Run linters
  run: npm run lint:prettier
```

[image]

[image]

.prettierrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  semi: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  singleQuote: true,
  printWidth: 120,
  tabWidth: 2,
  endOfLine: 'auto',
};
```

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // Specifies the ESLint parser
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    'plugin:prettier/recommended', // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and displays prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array.
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of JSX
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'react/prop-types': [2, { ignore: ['children'] }],
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect', // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
    },
  },
};
```

How can I fix it?